# Spring Security BCryptPasswordEncoder: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt with same paswords

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm developing a login service with kotlin and Spring Boot 2.5.5, and with a MySQL database. Everything seems to be working correctly (register user, delete user, update user), except that when I try to call the login endpoint from postman, I get an error:

`2021-10-26 18:16:28.558  WARN 26076 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt`

I've searched all over stackoverflow and I saw that other people have this problem, but none of the suggested answers worked for me (or even applied to my situation in some cases)

My SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(private val dataSource: DataSource) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password")
            .authorities("USER", "ADMIN", "CONTRIBUTOR")
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        http!!.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/contributor/**").hasAuthority("CONTRIBUTOR")
            .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
    }

    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,encrypted_password,\'true\' from dragonline.user where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_username,roles_name from dragonline.user_has_roles where user_username=?")
    }

}

class AppInitializer : WebApplicationInitializer {
    override fun onStartup(servletContext: ServletContext) {
        val root = AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext()
        root.register(SecurityConfig::class.java)

        servletContext.addListener(ContextLoaderListener(root))
        servletContext.addFilter("securityFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*")
    }
}
```

My login controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = ["/login"])
class Login(private val userRegistrationService: UserRegistrationService) {


    @PostMapping(path = ["/register"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun register(@RequestBody user: UserRegistrationDTO, response: HttpServletResponse): UserRegistrationDTO {
        user.confirmPassword()
        val domainUser = user.toDomain()
        userRegistrationService.saveUser(domainUser)
        response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED
        return user.maskPassword()
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(path = ["/find-user"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun login(@RequestBody user: UserLoginDTO, response: HttpServletResponse): UserLoginDTO {
        val userFound = userRegistrationService.findUser(user.username)
        println("The password stored ind DB is ${userFound?.encryptedPassword}")
        if (passwordEncoder().matches(userFound?.encryptedPassword, user.password)) {
            response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
            response.setHeader(
                "Session-ID",
                "${passwordEncoder().encode(user.username)}@.@${passwordEncoder().encode(user.password)}"
            )
        } else {
            response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND
        }
        return user.maskPassword()
    }


    @GetMapping(path = ["/delete-user/{userId}"])
    fun deleteUser(@PathVariable userId: String) {
        userRegistrationService.deleteUser(userId)
    }

}
```

The entry in my DB looks like this:

```
'test', '$2a$10$Z/FSxELmMtV2zpgFVYzDi.dprUybnzJxF6f/kZan7DqHfQ9VDjmQq', 'test@test.com', 'Tester', 'Testing a Test', NULL, '0'
```

The columns are username, encrypted_password, email, name, lastnames, session_id, session_active respectively

My UserService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
class UserRegistrationService(
    private val userRegistrationRepository: UserRegistrationRepository
) {

    fun findUser(userId: String) =
        userRegistrationRepository.findByUsername(userId) ?: userRegistrationRepository.findByEmail(userId)

    fun saveUser(user: UserRegistrationData) =
        userRegistrationRepository.save(user.toPersistence())

    fun deleteUser(userId: String) {
        val user = userRegistrationRepository.findByUsername(userId) ?: userRegistrationRepository.findByEmail(userId)
        ?: throw Exception("The user can't be deleted, because it doesn't exist")

        user.username.let {
            userRegistrationRepository.deleteByUsername(it)
        }
    }

}
```

My Repository:

```
@Repository
interface UserRegistrationRepository: JpaRepository<User, String> {

    fun findByUsername(username: String): User?
    fun findByEmail(email: String): User?
    fun deleteByUsername(username: String): Long
    fun deleteByEmail(email: String): Long

}
```

My extension functions file (I put my Eencoder bean here):

```
fun UserRegistrationData.toPersistence() = User(
    username = this.username,
    encryptedPassword = this.encryptedPassword,
    email = this.email,
    name = this.name,
    lastnames = this.lastnames,
    roles = this.roles.map { it.toPersistence() }.toHashSet()
)

fun UserRole.toPersistence() = Role(
    name = this.name
)
fun UserLoginDTO.maskPassword() = UserLoginDTO(
    username = this.username,
    password = "***********"
)

fun UserRegistrationDTO.confirmPassword() {
    if (this.password != this.confirmPassword) throw ResponseStatusException(
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        "The passwords don't match"
    )
}

fun UserRegistrationDTO.maskPassword() = UserRegistrationDTO(
    username = this.username,
    password = "***********",
    confirmPassword = "***********",
    email = this.email,
    name = this.name,
    lastnames = this.lastnames,
    admin = this.admin,
    contributor = this.contributor
)


fun UserRegistrationDTO.toDomain(): UserRegistrationData {
    val user = UserRegistrationData(
        name = this.name,
        lastnames = this.lastnames,
        email = this.email,
        username = this.username,
        encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode(this.password),
        roles = mutableListOf(UserRole.USER)
    )
    if(this.admin) user.roles.add(UserRole.ADMIN)
    if(this.contributor) user.roles.add(UserRole.CONTRIBUTOR)
    return user
}

@Bean
fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
    return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
}
```

My models (They're not all in the same package, that's why there's so many of them):

```
data class UserRegistrationDTO(
    val name: String? = null,
    val lastnames: String? = null,
    @field:NotBlank
    val username: String,
    @field:Email
    val email: String,
    @field:NotBlank
    val password: String,
    @field:NotBlank
    val confirmPassword: String,
    val admin: Boolean = false,
    val contributor: Boolean = false
)

data class UserLoginDTO(
    val username: String,
    val password: String
)

data class UserRegistrationData(
    val name: String? = null,
    val lastnames: String? = null,
    @field:NotBlank
    val username: String,
    @field:Email
    val email: String,
    @field:NotBlank
    val encryptedPassword: String,
    val roles: MutableList<UserRole> = mutableListOf(UserRole.USER)
)

class User(
    @Id
    var username: String,
    @Column
    var email: String,
    @Column
    var name: String?,
    @Column
    var lastnames: String?,
    @Column
    var encryptedPassword: String,
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_has_roles",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_username")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "roles_name")]
    )
    var roles: Set<Role>? = null
)
```

And finally my [Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEGvj.png)

If there's any more information that you need, please let me know.

Comment: I am. When doing the UserRegistrationDTO.toDomain() in my extension functions I'm encrypting the password:
`encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode(this.password)`
Maybe I should post my repository to have the whole path. I'm gonna edit to include it

Comment: please dont write that in comments, update your question using the "edit" button.

Comment: i have no idea why you are writing all this custom stuff, but there is several things you can do, for example, debug your application. I believe you are using the api wrong `matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword)` you need to switch the 2 input params

Comment: @Toerktumlare I'm writing all this to learn and practice :). And thank you! That was it... I can't believed I missed that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is because you mixed up the inputs to the `BCryptPasswordEncoder#matches` function.

your error message pointed me to [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/cb6ca7f4701b75d914834d405d16ecc93f0ecfe8/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java#L130) in the source code, which gave me a hint of what was wrong. Reading the source code is a good way to find out what is wrong.

The api tells us that `matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword)` and you gave it the encoded as the raw, and the raw as the encoded.

Comment: Thank you! This was my problem. I'd upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do so... I did mark it as the accepted answer.